# fetch location through GPS and NETWORK provider

Tags: android, networking, gps, location

In my app i want to get the user current location through `GPS` and I want to put the conditions like, if it will take more than 3min to fetch then it ll stop and fetching of location ll handover to `NETWORK`

How can I do that?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to see this link..this is the best link so far to get current Location.

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655)